# Добавить вкладку в редакторе wp

Tags: wordpress, плагин, tab

Здравствуйте. Каким образом можно добавить свою вкладку на странице создания новой страницы в CMS WordPress?
Пример на скрине (WR PageBuilder)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в настройках этого плагина нету такого? Должно быть

Comment: И что там должно быть? Для чего:

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов на скрине - ПРИМЕР. ТС хочет сделать также.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать плагин [Easy Responsive Tabs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-responsive-tabs/).

Comment: Насколько я понял ТС хочет в TinyMCE добавить вкладку. Правда, непонятно зачем.

Comment: Я тоже не понял зачем, но указанный мной плагин добавляет

Comment: Нет, не добавляет. Я вот даже специально проверил. Он только позволяет выводить контент табами, а не табы TinyMCE заиметь (аля дефолтные визуально/текст или как qtranslate для языков создаёт).

Comment: А, ну может быть и так. Но пока мы не знаем, что за табы имел ввиду ТС, мы не сможем понять, какой ответ ему нужен.

Comment: На скрине чётко видно - скрин от пейджбилера. Табы для разных способов формирования контента.  Так что о каких табах идёт речь - понятно. Непонятно лишь назначение. Хотя мне интересно и то зачем это ТСу и то, как это делать в принципе ;)